# Xslt analyze string error

Tags: xslt

In the XML below, I'm trying to create an id from the numbers in parenthesis. Therefore, I'm trying to grab numbers between the open and close parenthesis and then use them as part of the xmlid attribute.

XML input

```
<list>
<head>Commentator.</head>
<item>(32) Materia prima nullam formam habet omnino, nec universalem,
nec particularem, sed recipit primo formam universalem et medi-
ante illa, recipit omnes alias formas usque ad individuales.</item>
<item>(33) Item Commentator : species non est forma tantum, sed etiam
quid aggregatum ex materia et forma.</item>
<item>(34) Item universale non habet esse, nisi secundum quod est in anima.</item>
</list>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="tei:item">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\(([^\)]*)\)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="numberid"><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/></xsl:variable>
    <item xml:id="aa-meta-{$numberid}"><xsl:apply-templates/></item>
</xsl:template>
```

But it's not working.

Saxon is giving me the following error.

XTSE1130: At least one xsl:matching-substring or xsl:non-matching-substring element must be present

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [based on the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#regex-examples) that you need at least one of the `xsl:matching-substring` or `xsl:non-matching-substring` as a child on the `xsl:analyze-string element`.

One of the examples in the spec is as follows:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="body" regex="\[(.*?)\]">
  <xsl:matching-substring>
    <cite><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/></cite>
  </xsl:matching-substring>
  <xsl:non-matching-substring>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

Based on that you should be able to update your template to something like the below:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:item">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\(([^\)]*)\)">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <item xml:id="aa-meta-{regex-group(1)}"><xsl:apply-templates/></item>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```